# Constructing $\text{Sym}^2(V\oplus U)\cong \text{Sym}^2(U)\oplus \text{Sym}^2(V)\oplus (V\otimes U)$ and the same for $\text{Alt}^2$.

Tags: representation-theory

I need to be able to show that if there exist representations $\phi_1:G\to GL(V)$,  $\phi_2:G\to GL(U)$ that

- $\operatorname{Sym}^2(V\oplus U)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Sym}^2(U)\oplus \operatorname{Sym}^2V\oplus (V\otimes U)$
- $\operatorname{Alt}^2(V\oplus U)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Alt}^2(U)\oplus \operatorname{Alt}^2V\oplus (V\otimes U)$

Like, $(V \otimes  U)$ pops out in both cases when restricting $\operatorname{Sym}^2$. Clearly $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are related, but I don't see the isomorphism in either case.

Help? Tips?

Comment: Do you know the proof of isom. in the vectorspace level?  You just check group action is compatible with that.

Comment: What do you mean isomorphism in vector space level?